# Is it possible to dynamically inject the attribute using IoC like Ninject or other IoC?

Tags: c#, reflection, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, attributes

I am [extending my Object Property Value Diff](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/423157/how-to-diff-property-values-of-two-objects-using-gettype-getvalue) but I realized if an object has too many properties I may not want to diff them all. So I came up with the

```
public class IgnorePropertyDiffAttribute : System.Attribute
{
}
```

so that I can mark the properties I want the diff to ignore. However I don’t want to pollute my domain object with [IgnorePropertyDiff].

```
public class Role
{
    [IgnorePropertyDiff]
    public String Description { set; get; }
    public Double Salary { set; get; }
    public Boolean HasBonus { set; get; }
}
```

My question is that is it possible to dynamically inject the [IgnorePropertyDiff] using IoC like Ninject or other IoC? If I sound like an completely idiot please execuse me as I am only a junior-mid level c# developer. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Attributes are a compile-time feature, so no: you can't add them (or set values against them) using IoC.